# How do I activate Sidon's water bubble ability in TotK?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I'm currently exploring the Water Temple, where I can reach the water wheels. Now, every guide I've seen so far tells me I need to use the water bubble ability on the water wheels, but none of them tell how to do that.

How do I activate that ability, step by step? Which buttons to press, which items to select, etc.

PS. I remember the water bubble being introduced just before the mud worm combat, but I actually defeated that worm without much help from Sidon, by simply clearing up mud with splash arrows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can activate Sidon's water bubble by talking to him. This will put a water bubble around you, which acts as a shield. With a bubble around you, face the water wheel and slash with any weapon to launch a water projectile. This will turn the water wheel and progress the Water Temple.

Comment: Thanks! I actually missed a prior dialogue with Sidon and entered the temple alone, which is why I never saw I could talk to him.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted anwser didn't help me, so for everyone who is also stuck because Sidon does not follow you before: make sure to activate the water temple by walking up to the circle thing just under the sludge. This will make him follow you.

Comment: There are actually several places where you can lose Sidon. I lost him because I didn't speak to him just in front of the temple entrance. And I believe I did speak with him somewhere midway between the lake and the temple as well, which is yet another dialogue that can possibly be missed.

Comment: I think that it also always wants to pathfind to you, and sometimes, the temple just destroys his pathfinding.